# Python, remove all occurrences of string in list

Tags: python, string, list

Say i have a list:

```
main_list = ['bacon', 'cheese', 'milk', 'cake', 'tomato']
```

and another list:

```
second_list = ['cheese', 'tomato']
```

How can I remove all elements that are found in the second list, from the main list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the order is not important you can use [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
>>> main_array = ['bacon', 'cheese', 'milk', 'cake', 'tomato']
>>> second_array = ['cheese', 'tomato']
>>> set(main_array) & set(second_array)
set(['tomato', 'cheese'])
```

Here we use the intersection operator, `&`. Should you only want items not found in your second list, we can use difference, `-`:

```
>>> set(main_array) - set(second_array)
set(['cake', 'bacon', 'milk'])
```

Comment: That won't work if the order should be kept. Otherwise this is indeed the best solution. However, I think he wants to *remove* those elements so use `-` instead of `&`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - true, and didn't interpret `I want to all elements` right!

Answer (score 11):

```
new_array = [x for x in main_array if x not in second_array]
```

However, this is not very performant for large lists. You can optimize by using a set for `second_array`:

```
second_array = set(second_array)
new_array = [x for x in main_array if x not in second_array]
```

If the order of the items does not matter, you can use a set for both arrays:

```
new_array = list(set(main_array) - set(second_array))
```

Comment: I love how expressive python is :). It is like you are speaking english.

Comment: Nice answer, just a minor addition: you could optimize the order preserving variant by changing `second_array` into a set first: 
`second_set = set(second_array); new_array = [x for x in main_array if x not in second_set]`

Answer (score 3):

```
main_array = set(['bacon', 'cheese', 'milk', 'cake', 'tomato'])
second_array = (['cheese', 'tomato'])

main_array.difference(second_array)
>>> set(['bacon', 'cake', 'milk'])

main_array.intersection(second_array)
>>> set(['cheese', 'tomato'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [u'SQOOP', u'SOLR', u'SLIDER', u'SFTP', u'PIG', u'NODEMANAGER', u'JSQSH', u'HCAT', u'HBASE_REGIONSERVER', u'GANGLIA_MONITOR', u'FLUME_HANDLER', u'DATANODE', u'BIGSQL_WORKER']

p = [u'SQOOP', u'SOLR', u'SLIDER', u'SFTP']

l = [i for i in l if i not in [j for j in p]]

print l
[u'PIG', u'NODEMANAGER', u'JSQSH', u'HCAT', u'HBASE_REGIONSERVER', u'GANGLIA_MONITOR', u'FLUME_HANDLER', u'DATANODE', u'BIGSQL_WORKER']
```